# Parse query to find all objects of class A that are referenced by found objects of class B

Tags: parse-platform, relational, pfquery

I have 2 classes of Parse objects, A and B. Objects of class B have references to objects of class A via a key `@"referenceA"`.

**I want to execute a query that finds all objects A that are referenced by a certain set of objects B.**

I believe I had to use 2 queries: `queryB` is a constrained query on class B that returns this certain set of objects B, and then `queryA` that returns all objects A referenced by the objects found by `queryB`.
However I could not find a way to accomplish this, neither in the docs, nor in the posts:

```
[queryA whereKey:@"SELF" matchesKey:@"referenceA" inQuery:queryB];
```

apparently does not work here.  I also tried to use a predicate query without success.

Of course I could load the referenced objects A using `includeKey:@"referenceA"` in `queryB`, but then the returned objects are still of class B. Thus I cannot use such a `queryB` with the `includeKey:` in a `PFQueryTableViewController` to display the referenced objects A.
Any suggestion?

Comment: So `B` has a pointer column `referenceA` to `A` ? Does `A` have a reference to `B` and what else is `referenceA` used for ?

Comment: A does not have a reference to B. referenceA in an object B simply means "I am using this object A". I simply want to find out, which objects A are used by the found set of objects B.

Comment: Yes, so if you put the reference on `A` and then search for `A` used by a specified `B` you have your solution, the question is if you can and how difficult it would be

Comment: This should do it, but this back link makes my DB design more complex: Since the same object A can be used by many objects B, I had to store an array of back links in object A. And if an object B no longer uses its object A, I had to delete the back link in this array. And this should probably be done in Cloud Code to keep the DB consistent. I thought my query were rather simple, since it is so easily stated. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, easy statement, but to work with the table view controller means being a query which in this case I think makes it hard...

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comments, here's my take on your problem.

In my opinion, the `PFQueryTableViewController` restrains you unnecessarily in that it prevents you from doing exactly what you're doing. It forces you to construct a query that returns the objects that will be displayed, and provides no mechanism to display child nodes, for example. In my case, I ended up subclassing it to add methods that allow you to modify the data used in the table view after it is fetched from the server and before it's displayed on screen. This allows you to fetch a list of `B` objects from the server, use `includeKey` to also download the `A` objects, and then when you receive your data from the server, you can modify it to be the list of `A` objects that are referenced by the `B` objects returned by the query.

This will allow you to keep the complexity of your database down, if that's something you're concerned about.

Comment: Interesting, I did not think about this possibility. I assume you did overwrite loadObjects in your subclass to return the child objects?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that, and then probably provide some sort of method called `modifyObjects` or something which takes an array of `PFObjects` and returns another array of `PFObjects`.

Comment: I realized by now that loadObjects is a private method, but one could overwrite objectsDidLoad: and modify the objects property there. One disadvantage is that the child objects had to be sorted also there, whereas as 2 stage query, as I tried it first, would do it automatically using e.g. its orderByDescending: method. I still do not understand, why my approach `[queryA whereKey:@"SELF" matchesKey:@"referenceA" inQuery:queryB];` does not work...

Comment: It doesn't look like those methods are private to me. Regarding the query, maybe you could post the full query code?

Comment: The code is essentially (sorry for the formatting): `PFQuery *queryB = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"objectsB"]; PFQuery *queryA = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"objectsA"]; [queryA whereKey:@"SELF" matchesKey:@"referenceA" inQuery:queryB]; [queryA orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];` where `queryA` is returned to the `PFQueryTableViewController`.

Comment: My first reaction is that `queryB` might not be returning any objects because it has no constraints - I'm not sure if it's possible to construct such a query (I may well be wrong)

Comment: Actually this was an example reduced to the minimum to demonstrate the point. In my code `queryB` has constraints. Anyway, it is possible to have a query without constraints. One more thing: If one does assign the children to the objects property in the subclass, one looses all the features that a query has, not only sorting, but also to use further constraints on `queryA`.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem has been [answered in the Parse Google group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023361/parse-com-how-to-compare-pointer-keys-with-objects).
If one wants (like me) to use a single relational query (`whereKey:matchesKey:`), one has to add a string column storing the `objectId` of `referenceA` in `objectsB`.
Too bad that Parse apparently does not provide a reasonable solution to this pretty old problem.